# Problems with gcovr and regex expressions

Tags: regex, gcovr

I am trying to merge coverage data from specific files from multiple runs into a single "report". In each project I generate test coverage for different files, each in a separate project folder and then at the end I pick and choose what files to include in my final project. If I use the following command line where I select each file with a --filter [complete path and filename], it works perfectly and I get a combined report with just these files.  I also see it pick the files up in the log since I have -v option enabled shown below.

`gcovr -g -k -s --html --html-details -o code_coverage_summary2.html  -r . --filter firmware/crc32/crc_unit_tests.X/mcc_generated_files/boot/boot_verify_crc32.c --filter firmware/sha256/sha_unit_tests.X/mcc_generated_files/boot/boot_verify_sha256.c  --filter firmware/checksum/checksum_unit_tests.X/mcc_generated_files/boot/boot_verify_checksum16.c --filter firmware/command_processor/bootloader_pic_tb.X/mcc_generated_files/boot/boot_process.c -v > log4.txt`

Log File From above run
(many many lines before)

```
  currdir      C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test
  gcov_fname   C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test\firmware\sha256\sha_unit_tests.X\mcc_generated_files\boot\boot_verify_sha256.c.gcov
               ['        -', '    0', 'Source', 'boot_verify_sha256.c\n']
  source_fname None
  root         C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test
  fname        C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test\firmware\sha256\sha_unit_tests.X\mcc_generated_files\boot\boot_verify_sha256.c
Parsing coverage data for file C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test\firmware\sha256\sha_unit_tests.X\mcc_generated_files\boot\boot_verify_sha256.c
uncovered: {122}
covered:   {49: 1, 54: 1, 55: 1, 57: 1, 59: 1, 60: 1, 61: 1, 64: 1, 65: 1, 70: 1, 75: 1, 80: 1, 81: 1, 83: 1, 85: 1, 88: 1, 90: 1, 92: 1, 95: 1, 97: 1, 100: 1, 102: 1, 105: 1, 107: 1, 110: 1, 112: 1, 115: 1, 117: 1, 120: 1, 125: 1, 127: 1, 132: 1}
branches:  {}
noncode:   {128, 129, 3, 131, 133, 6, 134, 9, 12, 23, 27, 30, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 44, 46, 48, 50, 51, 53, 56, 58, 62, 63, 66, 67, 69, 71, 72, 74, 76, 77, 79, 82, 84, 86, 87, 89, 91, 93, 94, 96, 98, 99, 101, 103, 104, 106, 108, 109, 111, 113, 114, 116, 118, 119, 121, 123, 124, 126}
Finding source file corresponding to a gcov data file
  currdir      C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test
  gcov_fname   C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test\firmware\crc32\crc_unit_tests.X\mcc_generated_files\boot\boot_verify_crc32.c.gcov
               ['        -', '    0', 'Source', 'boot_verify_crc32.c\n']
  source_fname None
  root         C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test
  fname        C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test\firmware\crc32\crc_unit_tests.X\mcc_generated_files\boot\boot_verify_crc32.c
Parsing coverage data for file C:\Users\murphy\Downloads\archive (5)\archive\src\test\firmware\crc32\crc_unit_tests.X\mcc_generated_files\boot\boot_verify_crc32.c
uncovered: set()
covered:   {50: 1, 55: 1, 56: 1, 57: 1, 62: 1, 63: 1, 65: 1, 67: 1, 70: 1, 72: 1, 74: 1, 77: 1, 79: 1, 82: 1, 84: 1, 87: 1, 89: 1, 92: 1, 94: 1, 97: 1, 99: 1, 102: 1, 104: 1, 108: 1, 109: 1, 110: 1, 112: 1, 114: 1, 120: 1, 121: 1, 123: 1, 128: 1, 129: 1, 131: 1, 134: 1, 139: 1}
branches:  {}
noncode:   {3, 132, 133, 6, 135, 136, 9, 138, 12, 140, 141, 23, 28, 31, 33, 35, 38, 40, 45, 47, 49, 51, 52, 54, 58, 59, 61, 64, 66, 68, 69, 71, 73, 75, 76, 78, 80, 81, 83, 85, 86, 88, 90, 91, 93, 95, 96, 98, 100, 101, 103, 105, 106, 111, 113, 115, 122, 124}
Finding source file corresponding to a gcov data file
```

(many many lines after)

I have many more files to add and I really do not want to have a specific filter for each unique path & filename.  What I want is a filter for all of the files that have the pattern  `boot_verify*.c` in them.  I have tried different regex expressions shown below but they all return no files selected.

```
--filter '(.+/)?boot_verify(.*)\.c$' 
--filter '(.+/)?boot_verify_([a-z][A-Z][0-9]+)\.c$'
--filter '(.+/)?boot_verify_([a-z][A-Z][0-9]*)\.c$'
```

To force the issue I tried a regex with just a single file name below and even that did not work.

```
--filter '(.+/)?boot_verify_crc32\.c$'
```

I would really like to get the wild card pattern and the specific filename pattern working.  What am I doing wrong?

Ken

Comment: Which version of gcovr are you using? Version 5 contains relevant fixes. You are running Windows. Which shell/command line are you using to run the gcovr command? Bash? Cmd.exe? Different command lines have different escaping rules.

Comment: I am using 4.1 and will see about upgrading.  I am also running on windows and cmd. 
After reading your post and re-reading the user guide, I switched my command from using ticks around my filter to quotes and it's now processing the regex command correctly.  Thank you for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

When using regexes in command line arguments, they must be properly escaped.

- When using **Bash** or another **POSIX shell** on **Linux** or other **Unix**-like operating systems including **MacOS**, surround the regex with **single quotes**. For example:

  ```sh
  gcovr --filter '(.+/)?boot_verify_crc32\.c$'
  ```

  See the [*Quoting* section in the *Bash Reference Manual*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Quoting) or [in the POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html). In particular, escaping/quoting is necessary if the regex contains any of the following characters, or space characters:

  ```
  | & ; < > ( ) $ ` \ " ' * ? [ # ˜ = %
  ```
- When using **cmd.exe** on **Windows**, surround the regex with **double quotes**:

  ```
  gcovr --filter "(.+/)?boot_verify_crc32\.c$"
  ```

  I cannot find a good reference for this, though [Parsing C Command-Line Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/parsing-c-command-line-arguments?view=msvc-170) seems to contain the relevant rules.
- When using **PowerShell** on **Windows**, surround the regex with **single quotes**:

  ```
  gcovr --filter '(.+/)?boot_verify_crc32\.c$'
  ```

  See the sections [*about Quoting Rules*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2) and [*about Parsing*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-7.2#argument-mode) in the PowerShell documentation. In particular, escaping/quoting is necessary if the regex contains any of the following characters, or space characters:

  ```
  ' " ` , ; ( ) { } | & < > @ #
  ```

Additionally, please note that gcovr 4.1 is from 2018. Since then, some fixes relating to Windows support and filter matching have been implemented. Assuming that you installed gcovr as `pip3 install gcovr`, you can upgrade to the latest stable release with:

```
pip3 install -U gcovr
```